# Failed to decode current backend config error when doing terraform destroy

Tags: terraform

I encounter this error when doing `terraform destroy`

[image: terraformErr1]

When using the suggested command `terraform init -reconfigure` the issue is resolved but I get instead this warning every time now.

[image: terraformErr2]

However, I didn't change anything in this code. Is it the conflict of Terraform version?

[image: terraformErr3]

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform is reporting this warning because your child module in `../modules/geotwin_service` includes a `backend "gcs"` block, but backend configurations are relevant only in the root module of a Terraform configuration.

This warning is new in recent versions of Terraform, but prior versions of Terraform also ignored this backend configuration. The only change is that Terraform now explicitly warns about it rather than ignoring it silently, because otherwise it can be confusing as to why Terraform is not making any use of that backend configuration.

Given that you were able to run `terraform init -reconfigure` successfully I expect that you *also* have a `backend "gcs"` block in your root module, which is the one Terraform is using here. Given that, you might consider removing the unused `backend "gcs"` block from `../modules/geotwin_service`, although that would be safe to do only if that module is used *exclusively* as a child module, and never directly as a root module.

Comment: Thank you very much @Martin Atkins for this clear explanation. I will consult with my colleague to see if we can remove this and test this.